# Subquery with WHERE clause => Column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I try to get the top 3 length per film for each actor. My query looks my this.

```
SELECT fullname, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fullname ORDER BY length DESC) as f_rank,
   length
      FROM
   (SELECT actor.first_name || ' ' || actor.last_name as fullname, film.length
   FROM film_actor
   JOIN film
      ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
   JOIN actor
      ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id) sub
WHERE f_rank <= 3
```

So it looks like without the where clause

```
fullname    f_rank  length
Adam Grant  1   173
Adam Grant  2   173
Adam Grant  3   156
Adam Grant  4   155
Adam Grant  5   152
Adam Grant  6   148
Adam Grant  7   141
```

`WHERE fullname = 'Alan Grant'` works perfectly. With `f_rank` I get the following error:

```
column "f_rank" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here? I´m totally confused.

Comment: Column aliases defined in the `select` cannot be referenced in the `where` for that `select`.  Use a CTE or subquery.

Comment: `FROM ... SELECT ... WHERE` - columns defined in SELECT cannot be used in WHERE at the same level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a column alias defined in the `select`.  But, it doesn't make sense to do the ranking on the *name* of the actor when you can do it on the `id`.  If that meets your needs, just move the logic to the subquery:

```
SELECT fullname, f_rank, length
FROM (SELECT a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name as fullname, f.length,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.actor_id ORDER BY f.length DESC) as f_rank
      FROM film_actor fa JOIn
           film f
           ON fa.film_id = f.film_id JOIN
           actor a
           ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
     ) af
WHERE f_rank <= 3
```